# Apriori without left (before) and right (after) side

Tags: r, apriori

I use apriory algorithm for Market Basket Analysis in R. There is left (lhs) and right side (rhs) to look for:

- What customers buy before buying selected items (rhs is set, lhs is calculated)
- What customers buy after buying selected items (lhs is set, rhs is calculated)

But I don't care about order of bought items. I'd like to calculate with the A item regardless the B item is on left (before) or after (right) side. Every side has the same value for me.

Is there any modification of apriori which doesn't care about sides?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question. Apriori which doesn't care for sides?

Check the arules package: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/arules/docs/apriori and use inspect(rules) to get all the rules.

Try 
rules <- subset(rules, subset = rhs %pin% "A.item=") to screen out rules with only 'A' items on RHS, if that is what you are seeking.